# Automate Google Calendar Access Authorization Code Retrieval - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, authorization, google-calendar-api

I'm new to NodeJS and any help will really be appreciated.
I am currently making an application to access a user’s Google Calendar.
Right now I am using the code snippet for NodeJS from the following link, using my project's credentials.

https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs

After running the script there is a link which directs the user to the Google Login page, where the user can login from a chosen account and then authorize Full Calendar access to the app.
Upon authorizing Calendar access to the application, the user is presented with a Unique code which must be copied into the terminal (prompted by the script) which then generates a token and stores it in token.json.

I want to automate the retrieval of the unique code (generated for the user upon granting access) without the user having to copy the code and paste it in the terminal.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Also, the page that shows the unique token to be copied and the steps preceding have been shown in the attached screenshots.

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7AYj.png)

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2NUA.png)

[Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpI58.png)

[Step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9LfM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a Service Account. They are like "dummy users" which don't require user interaction to be authorized. You will have to grant your users access to the Service Account.

You can follow this [guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#creatinganaccount) to set it up:

1. Open the [Service accounts page](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts).
2. If prompted, select a project, or create a new one.
3. Click **+ Create service account**.
4. Under **Service account details**, type a name, ID, and description for the service account, then click **Create**.
5. Optional: Under **Service account permissions**, select the IAM roles to grant to the service account, then click **Continue**.
6. Optional: Under **Grant users access to this service account**, add the users or groups that are allowed to use and manage the service account.
7. Click **+ Create key**, then click **Create**.

Then, use the NodeJS Service Account [guide](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#service-account-credentials) to use the new Credentials.

---

Instead of Service Accounts, you can also do it by saving the Refresh Token to request new Access Tokens programatically, without user interaction. See [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#refresh) documentation.

Comment: Thanks alot! got us on the right track i feel,  We're currently using the link in your second solution (which was more relevant to us as this is a client side  web app) working on using refresh tokens to generate new access tokens using OAuth2.0 endpoints as directed at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#example. 
Hopefully this ends up working out.     Really appreciate the help!

Comment: You are welcome! If it was helpful to you, please consider accepting the answer so others might find this solution too :)